# Dynamic segment is not working in ember

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js

I'm trying to have this kind of a route in my project where the last part is user ID.
*http://localhost:4200/profile/5621140ff60f6dee985b88aa*

I need to display details of user that have the above ID only.But  after creating following files i found that all the users are loaded to template. not only the user that  have specific Id. Why is that??

router.js

```
Router.map(function() {

  this.resource('profile', { path: '/profile/:user_id' });

   });
```

route/profile.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(params, transition) {

        return this.store.query("user", params.user_id);
    }

});
```

profile.hbs

```
<h2>Welcome user</h2>

{{#each item in model}}
{{item.firstName}}
{{/each}}
```

server.js

```
app.get('/api/profile', function(req,res) {
    UserModel.find({},function(err,docs) {
        if(err) {
            res.send({error:err});
        }
        else {
            res.send({user:docs});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `store.query` returns a collection, you should be using `queryRecord`, and sending back a single record.  dynamic segments in ember in general are expecting a single record

Comment: sidenote: `this.resource` is deprecated for `this.route`. `{{each` syntax also changed: http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_code-in-code-syntax-for-code-each-code